# How can initial segment of the set of all natural numbers is equal to itself

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I'm studying ordinal numbers in Halmos's book (page 75). After the definition of ordinal number, he proves that $w^+$ is an ordinal number where $w$ is the set of all natural numbers.

In the last part of the proof, he states that $s(w) = w$ **"by definition of order**" (where $s(w)$ is the initial segment of $w$). (I don't actually know which definition has been applied in this context)

I couldn't understand how $s(w) = w$ because as far as I know, we don't have the notion of $x \lt w$ where $x$ is a natural numbers (i think we only have the order defined on the set of natural number, in other words, we compare 2 natural numbers but not a natural number and the set of all natural numbers). And moreover, I think even if we can "compare" a natural number and $w$, how could we make sure that the initial segment of $w$ is equal to $w$ ? (i.e. I think there can be for example 2 times the number 1 appear in the initial segment i.e. $s(w) =$ {0; 1; 1; ...}).

Could you please help me out of this misunderstanding ? Thank you very much

> An example of an ordinal number that is not a natural number is the set $w$ consisting of all the natural numbers. This means that we can ready "count" farther than we could before; whereas before the only numbers at our disposal were the elements of $w$, now we have $w$ itself.
>
> We have also the successor $w^+$ of $w$; this set is ordered in the obvious way, and, moreover the obvious ordering is a well ordering that satisfies the condition imposed on ordinal numbers.
>
> Indeed, if $x \in w^+$, then by the definition of successor, either $x \in w$ in which case we already know that $s(x) = x$ or else $x = w$, in which case $s(x) = w$, **by the definition of order**, so that again $s(x) = x$

Answer (score 1):

Halmos defines an ordinal number in the paragraph before the ones you are quoting:

> The chief application of the axiom of substitution is in extending the
> process of counting far beyond the natural numbers. From the present
> point of view, the crucial property of a natural number is that it is a well
> ordered set such that the initial segment determined by each element is
> equal to that element. (Recall that if $m$ and $n$ are natural numbers, then
> $m < n$ means $m\in n$; this implies that $\{m \in w: m < n\} = n$.) This is the
> property on which the extended counting process is based; the fundamental
> definition in this circle of ideas is due to von Neumann. An ordinal
> number is defined as a well ordered set a such that $s(x) = x$ for all $x$ in $\alpha$;
> here $s(x)$ is, as before, the initial segment $\{\eta \in\alpha: \eta < x\}$.

Since the initial segment of $x$ is $x$ itself, we must have that $y\in s(x)$ (which is the same as $y<x$) if and only if $y\in x$; in other words, the ordering of an ordinal set is the same as $\in$.

When Halmos says that $\omega^+$ is ordered in the obvius way, he means that elements of $\omega$ are ordered in the common way and $\omega$ is bigger than all of them (you can easily check that this is a well order), which matches with $m<n$ if and only if $m\in n$, because we already know this is true for $m, n\in\omega$, and we have $m<\omega$ for all  $m\in\omega^+$ different from $\omega$, which are precisely the $m\in\omega$.

Comment: Hello, thanks so much for your answer. However, it seems to me that you did not directly answer why $s(w) = w$, could you please help me with some enlightments ?

Comment: The obvious order to which Halmos refers is such that if $m$ and $n$ are natural numbers and $m<n$ in the common sense and $m<\omega$ if $m$ is a natural number. So the set of predecessors of $\omega$ is the set of natural numbers; this is, $s(\omega)=\omega$. If you don't know why this is "obvious", I think it is because it is the only way that you can order $\omega^+$ to satisfy the definition of ordinal number.

Comment: Hello, I come back after thinking very hard about your comment that "it is the only way...". Do you mean that by defining the order $\lt$ = $\in$ is the only way to order a set so that it can become an ordinal number ? Could you please explain me why in the definition of ordinal number given by Halmos, there is no word saying that the order is actually the $\in$ relation, but we must understand that it is the $\in$ order that must be used when we talk about ordinal numbers ? Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Hello, the reason why an ordinal $\alpha$ must be ordered with the belonging relation is because of the defining property $s(x)=x$ for all $x\in\alpha$. An element $y$ of $\alpha$ is less than x if and only if $y\in s(x)$, so by $s(x)=x$, we have $y<x$ if and only if $y\in x$. This means that the relation $<$ of $\alpha$ relates two elements precisely when the first belongs to the second.